# Mapcache <template> or <grid> directive

Tags: mapserver, mapcache, zxy

My goal is to use mapcache to generate a ZXY tileset. This tileset can then be used directly by the client with no server requirement.

The reason for mapcache is that I have a set of mapserver map files that contain all of my styling.

I have configured mapcache.xml as follows:-

```
<cache name="disk_test" type="disk" layout="template">
    <template>/tmp/disk_test/rbwm_mastermap/{z}/{x}/{y}.{ext}</template>
</cache>

<tileset name="test_zxy">
    <source>MY MAPFILE SOURCE</source>
    <cache>disk_test</cache>
    <grid>ZXY</grid>
    <format>PNG</format>
    <metatile>1 1</metatile>
    <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
    <expires>3600</expires>
    <auto_expire>2678400</auto_expire>
</tileset>

<grid name="ZXY">
    <size>256 256</size>
    <extent>-20037508.3427892480 -20037508.3427892480 20037508.3427892480 20037508.3427892480</extent>
    <srs>EPSG:3857</srs>
    <units>m</units>
    <resolutions>2000 1000 500 400 200 100 50 25 20 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2.5 2 1.5 1 0.3 0.2</resolutions>
</grid>
```

The following request creates a tile in **20/77961/104498.png**

```
SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&
REQUEST=GetMap&
LAYERS=test_zxy&
WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&
FORMAT=image/png&
SRS=EPSG:3857&
TILED=true&
DPI=72&
MAP_RESOLUTION=72&
FORMAT_OPTIONS=dpi:72&
TRANSPARENT=TRUE&BBOX=-79492.34278900176286697,6713979.65721099823713303,-79236.34278900176286697,6714235.65721099823713303
```

My calculations show that this is wrong as it should be closer to:-

**20/522208/348614.png**

Am I doing something wrong in my grid or template?

Comment: Just in case it helps anyone else. To use these tiles in Openlayers you will need to use -y instead of y in the url:-  var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
              url: 'http://SERVER/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [-79492.34278900176286697,6713979.65721099823713303],
          zoom: 20
        })
      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resolutions do not look correct. Try:

```
<resolutions>156543.0339280410 78271.51696402048 39135.75848201023 19567.87924100512 9783.939620502561 4891.969810251280 2445.984905125640 1222.992452562820 611.4962262814100 305.7481131407048 152.8740565703525 76.43702828517624 38.21851414258813 19.10925707129406 9.554628535647032 4.777314267823516 2.388657133911758 1.194328566955879 0.5971642834779395</resolutions>
```

Comment: Spot on thanks! Note well I had to add a few more to go down further zoom levels  <resolutions>156543.0339280410 78271.51696402048 39135.75848201023 19567.87924100512 9783.939620502561 4891.969810251280 2445.984905125640 1222.992452562820 611.4962262814100 305.7481131407048 152.8740565703525 76.43702828517624 38.21851414258813 19.10925707129406 9.554628535647032 4.777314267823516 2.388657133911758 1.194328566955879 0.5971642834779395,0.2984505969011938, 0.1492252984505969, 0.07461264922529845</resolutions>